# Java SQL Server getImportedKeys on all user defined tables

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, database-metadata

I am currently working on SQL Server. I'd need to get all the relationships between tables in a schema. I was able to perform this operation by getMetaData on Oracle through:

```
meta.getImportedKeys(con.getCatalog(), dbName, null);
```

The same does not occur on SQL Server as the former throws the exception requiring the third parameter. My idea is to get the list of all the tables with

```
metaData.getTables(null, dbName, "%", null)
```

and iterating by substituting the third parameter on getImportedKeys.
Is there an alternative to obtain the list of all relations from SQL Server?

Comment: In SQL Server the database name is not the same thing as the schema. Also some JDBC drivers require you to use `"%"` for the `tablePattern` parameter.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, you're right. But even "%" does not yield results.